# JQuery - Passing multiple text inputs to a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm afraid I don't do a lot of work with JQuery, and was unable to find an answer to this in the documentation.  I am trying to use JQuery to pass multiple text inputs to a hidden field.  So far I have got the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#textinput1').blur(function() {
            $('input[name=hiddenField]').val($('#textinput1').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works fine for pulling a single line over to the hidden field.  However, I have two additional fields that I need to also display in the hidden field so that the value of the hidden field represents all three of these text inputs.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the names of the hidden input fields and the non-hidden ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers your exact question.

```
$(function(){
        $('#textinput1,#textinput2,#textinput3').blur(function() {
            $('input[name=hiddenField]').val(
                      $('#textinput1').val() + " " + 
                      $('#textinput2').val() + " " + 
                      $('#textinput3').val());
        });
    });
```

But generally speaking, unless there's a good reason not to, we'd want a different hidden fields for each one of these.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Yeah, originally I wanted to try to use unique hidden fields, but unfortunately this website isn't going to allow that.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1971129 You're welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Feel free to make a permanent account. Well written questions like yours are always welcome.

Comment: Much appreciated!  I certainly will; I use the site regularly, but up until now a quick search was all I needed to yield an answer.  Thanks again!